# How to perform svn update to an already existing svn directory

Tags: svn, jenkins

I have two repo A and B. First i checkout repo A to my Eulen directory.

It contain module folder with some modules. Now i want to take updates of repository B to modules folder in my Eulen->modules folder.

So my question is when i go for taking modules from repo B, it is cleaning up the modules folder of my directory and putting modules in repo B.

For instead of replacing the modules folder, i just needed the modules of repo B with already existing modules in modules folder.

How can i perform checkout of modules from repo B to modules folder with replacing already existing modules?

Regards

Comment: Have you considered [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to make this so far as i know.
You can try externals or a relocate, but does not what you need.

Maybe its better to use Git. This offers ways to do this.

Here you can find a quick [Git Hosting Service](http://www.saas-secure.com/en/git-hosting/index.html) to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with SVN.

Subversion has a Meta Directory (.svn or _svn) in each Directory it checkouts. Basically this Meta information corresponds to a particular path in a repository. It won't allow you to add another repo content's via svn in the same place.

Rather, you can ->

- Use [SVN Externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html)
- Checkout the modules in repo B in a seperate directoru and then use a script to move them to a desired location.